# Why myListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() on listener return same that com.package.object@1234556

Tags: adb

in the event listener to my custom ListView I need to get data from the items on the list but the mainListView.getItemAtPosition (position). toString () returns me something like this: com.package.object @ 1234556

This is the class of the object

```
public class ItemPuesto {
protected long id;
protected String rutaImagen;
protected String nombre;
protected String tipo;


public ItemPuesto() {
    this.nombre = "";
    this.tipo = "";
    this.rutaImagen = "";
}

public ItemPuesto(long id, String nombre, String tipo) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.tipo = tipo;
    this.rutaImagen = "";
}

public ItemPuesto(long id, String nombre, String tipo, String rutaImagen) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.tipo = tipo;
    this.rutaImagen = rutaImagen;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getRutaImagen() {
    return rutaImagen;
}

public void setRutaImagen(String rutaImagen) {
    this.rutaImagen = rutaImagen;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}

public void setTipo(String tipo) {
    this.tipo = tipo;
}
```

this is adapter:

```
public class ItemPuestoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
protected Activity activity;
protected ArrayList<ItemPuesto> items;


public ItemPuestoAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<ItemPuesto> items) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.items = items;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}


@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return items.get(position).getId();
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;

    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout, null);
    }

    ItemPuesto item = items.get(position);

    ImageView image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imagen);
    int imageResource = activity.getResources().getIdentifier(item.getRutaImagen(), null, activity.getPackageName());
    image.setImageDrawable(activity.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource));

    TextView nombre = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
    nombre.setText(item.getNombre());

    TextView tipo = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tipo);
    tipo.setText(item.getTipo());

    return vi;
}
```

and this is listener

```
mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id)
            {



                //i.putExtra("seleccion", mainListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());


                //startActivity(i);


                alerta.setMessage(mainListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                alerta.show();

            }
        });
```

Comment: Development questions are off-topic here. You will have better chances in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

My friend you are getting correct output from the object of `ItemPuesto`.

The `toString()` function returns the hash value for the object.
If you need a particular output from using `toString()` function then you must override `toString()` in your `ItemPuesto` class.

For example you can override to get value of `nombre` like following;

```
public String toString(){
  return nombre;
}
```